# fps drop Multiresolution modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers, multiresolution

The Situation
I modeled a Human mesh for an RPG-Game and created severel animations.
I reworked the mesh and sculpted ( the first time ) using The multiresolution modifier like in a tutorial.

TheProblem
If i run the animation without the Multirresolutionmodifier Preview The fps-Count is 60 (and all is fine ) .If i activate the first level it drops to 15 and if i activate my final wanted Preview level 4 it drops to 1.5 or even lower.
I am relative new to blender and didn´t find much information about this Problem while searching.
Only some optimize approach in the settings which didnt change noticable the situation. And that Nvidia and multiresolution can cause some Issues (maybe only in the past) I dont know why exactly.
In Unity it runs smooth with Multiresolutionmodifiers applyed.

Graphiccard GeForce GTX 660Ti newest driver
and on a better pc from college its the same problem.


If you guys could take a look on it. 

I would realy thankful about it.

Any suggestion would be nice.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dj8AqEc_YbHJ_aPsK5086GpdcTTegFev

Comment: What is the target game engine? You won't be able to export the multires modifer anyways. It's likely going to be have to be baked onto the lowres mesh as material maps. Other than that, you can simply turn off multires during animation.

Comment: Unity but i wanna watch the Animations in blender to see the actual result and change it  if needed. It is also one project for studies. Create a human and animate him. Cause of this my professor should be able to watch the animations in blender. Another project is an game in unity for which i currently use this model and his animations.

Comment: I probably didn't explain it properly. *You can't export the multires modifier to unity.* Don't you want to have the animations appear the same in Blender as in Unity?

Comment: Yes , currently in Unitys ingame mode the animation and the wanted human (view with multiresolutionmodifier applyed wanted result) shows as wanted. But i wanna see the animation in blender also. Smooth animation without heavy fps drop when running animation.